# How do I plot an exponential curve in R?

Tags: r, regression, exponential-distribution

I am trying to plot an exponential curve (`nls`) through this data set in R.

abm is a text file with the following data=

```
x=

1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,3,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,2,1,5,5,1,4,3,4,3,3,5,7,2,4,6,4,4,3,6,5,5,3,4,3,4,7,5,7,11,3,6,6,6,9,1,1,3,9,3,4,6,6,12,6,2,12,8,2,4,12,6,8,9,6,5,4,4,11,4,18,8,10,8,17,5,16,16,6,5,18,3,1,10,2,11,21,8,11,15,9,13,14,3,11,17,18,9,16,17,12,18,2,9,17,14,14,5,21,21,13,17,15,9,1,18,17,7,2,17,23,22,27,10,10,17,25,12,28,12,13,14,5,20,13,3,17,16,21,11,27,19,19,19,22,19,6,30,16,13,10,30,18,17,30,4,23,20,18,5,22,10,37,38,19,36,36,34,37,36,25,30,26,22,32,30,30,45,18,25,42,44,24,38,34,14,16,6,36,26,29,28,44,20,31,45,39,43,46,47,34,46,47,40,48,43,49,46,48,49,49

y=

18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,18.36734694,20.40816327,20.40816327,20.40816327,20.40816327,20.40816327,20.40816327,22.44897959,22.44897959,22.44897959,22.44897959,24.48979592,24.48979592,26.53061224,26.53061224,26.53061224,28.57142857,28.57142857,30.6122449,30.6122449,32.65306122,32.65306122,34.69387755,34.69387755,36.73469388,38.7755102,38.7755102,38.7755102,40.81632653,40.81632653,40.81632653,40.81632653,40.81632653,42.85714286,44.89795918,48.97959184,51.02040816,51.02040816,53.06122449,55.10204082,57.14285714,61.2244898,61.2244898,63.26530612,63.26530612,63.26530612,67.34693878,67.34693878,69.3877551,77.55102041,77.55102041,77.55102041,79.59183673,81.63265306,81.63265306,89.79591837,89.79591837,95.91836735,104.0816327,112.244898,124.4897959,130.6122449,134.6938776,138.7755102,146.9387755,146.9387755,151.0204082,161.2244898,163.2653061,165.3061224,167.3469388,169.3877551,169.3877551,169.3877551,171.4285714,181.6326531,185.7142857,208.1632653,220.4081633,224.4897959,230.6122449,240.8163265,240.8163265,246.9387755,267.3469388,269.3877551,271.4285714,304.0816327,306.122449,310.2040816,318.3673469,332.6530612,342.8571429,355.1020408,355.1020408,387.755102,395.9183673,395.9183673,397.9591837,404.0816327,430.6122449,448.9795918,451.0204082,455.1020408,465.3061224,465.3061224,467.3469388,469.3877551,518.3673469,522.4489796,528.5714286,532.6530612,534.6938776,534.6938776,553.0612245,563.2653061,569.3877551,577.5510204,583.6734694,583.6734694,600,612.244898,618.3673469,628.5714286,689.7959184,714.2857143,730.6122449,738.7755102,748.9795918,802.0408163,855.1020408,875.5102041,895.9183673,906.122449,924.4897959,934.6938776,948.9795918,955.1020408,977.5510204,989.7959184,997.9591837,1014.285714,1026.530612,1040.816327,1071.428571,1083.673469,1102.040816,1110.204082,1126.530612,1130.612245,1142.857143,1185.714286,1218.367347,1224.489796,1236.734694,1242.857143,1248.979592,1259.183673,1314.285714,1424.489796,1430.612245,1467.346939,1495.918367,1502.040816,1528.571429,1534.693878,1540.816327,1557.142857,1608.163265,1632.653061,1657.142857,1691.836735,1691.836735,1738.77551,1765.306122,1916.326531,1928.571429,2055.102041,2057.142857,2059.183673,2071.428571,2104.081633,2155.102041,2171.428571,2193.877551,2226.530612,2251.020408,2357.142857,2508.163265,2553.061224,2579.591837,2581.632653,2738.77551,2740.816327,2759.183673,2897.959184,2902.040816,2904.081633,2914.285714,3057.142857,3193.877551,3204.081633,3306.122449,3373.469388,3381.632653,3428.571429,3491.836735,3604.081633,3875.510204,4028.571429,4273.469388,4781.632653,5002.040816,5004.081633,5575.510204,5683.673469,6073.469388,6185.714286,6212.244898,6391.836735,6434.693878,6442.857143,6591.836735,6591.836735,6724.489796,6775.510204,8030.612245,8710.204082,9410.204082,9434.693878,9991.836735,10787.7551,11000,11048.97959,11524.4898,12085.71429,12881.63265,13620.40816,14087.7551,14089.79592,15636.73469,16361.22449,16440.81633,16759.18367,16846.93878,18267.34694,20240.81633,22004.08163,22816.32653,26493.87755,29981.63265,32777.55102,33724.4898,37240.81633,39116.32653,54540.81633,56977.55102,73912.2449
```

I use this R script to make a scatter plot:

```
plot(log(abm), xlab="Log10 (Number of sites occupied)", ylab="(Log10) Mean local abundance", xlim=c(0,4),pch=20)
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to plot an exponential curve through this data. Can anybody please help with this? I know I need to use "nls" but I cannot seem to do it. I am a noob at R and would appreciate any advice and help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

You mean something like this?

```
mdl1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = xy)
mdl2 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = xy)
mdl3 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3), data = xy)
mdl4 <- lm(y ~ I(x^2), data = xy)

prd <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 50, by = 0.5))

result <- prd
result$mdl1 <- predict(mdl1, newdata = prd)
result$mdl2 <- predict(mdl2, newdata = prd)
result$mdl3 <- predict(mdl3, newdata = prd)
result$mdl4 <- predict(mdl4, newdata = prd)

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

result <-  melt(result, id.vars = "x", variable.name = "model",
                value.name = "fitted")
ggplot(result, aes(x = x, y = fitted)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data = xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = model), size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, thanks! But how do I get this on the log plot? Cheers!

Comment: Oh, and how do I get the P values for the regression models?

Comment: @user28246 try `summary(mdl1)`.

Comment: Oh yeah, cheers, and is it easy to get the plot looking like the imgur link I posted with log axis? Thanks so much!

Comment: None of these models are "exponential curves." None of them are appropriate for the strong heteroscedasticity apparent in the data, either: Unlike the models shown here, a model that accounted for that would fit the data extremely well for small $x$ where the vertical scatter is small.

Answer (score 4):

You have two variables which you both log. The resulting scatter plot by eye looks approximately straight. That suggests a power function. Why the interest in exponential curves? An exponential $y = y_0 \exp(bx)$ implies that $\log y$ is linear in $x$, not that $\log y$ is linear in $\log x$.

(Note: this is corrected over first posting.)

Comment: Oh, so you think it is linear? I got really good fits with an exponential curve in excel...wanted to plot it in R. Shall I stick with linear curves then? Cheers for the reply!

Comment: Presumably there is some science here underlying your analysis. At a guess this is ecology. Do you think that abundance explodes with #sites occupied, as an exponential model implies?

Comment: Yes, this is ecology. Normally this is a linear relationship. However, it looked like an exponential curve would fit my data better...

Comment: I've plotted log y versus x and log y versus log x for your data and there's no question that the second (which you give) is better. As said, that's a power function, not an exponential. I don't know what you plotted exactly but judging fit is easiest when the reference curve is a straight line. (Any confusion here might reflect loose use of "exponential": see my answer for what I take to be the exponential model in question.)

Comment: Ah, thanks so much for looking into this. So I should just fit a linear model? Do you know how to plot this over the log plot I provide above? I am no good in R...sorry and thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you think this looks right, then? http://i.imgur.com/f8p1qxS.jpg

Comment: Seems par for the course. I don't use R routinely.

Comment: @user28246 what a linear model means is that the parameters are linear in nature. This does not explicitly mean that you fit a "straight line". I hope there's no confusion around that.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment but I'm making it an answer so I can show the picture.

This data doesn't seem to be fitted by an exponential curve. In fact, if you look at log(y) vs x, it has got a pretty clear kink in it at around x=8 or x=9.

[image: log y vs x shows a nonlinear relationship]

Answer (score 0):

For the standard `plot()` variant of Roman's answer, you would use something like the following to plot the lines after plotting the scatterplot:

```
mdl4 <- lm(y ~ I(x^2), data = abm)    
plot(log(abm))
lines(sort(abm$x), predict(mdl4, list(x=sort(abm$x))), lwd=2, col='red')
```

Very clean and concise in this case. The `sort()` function is necessary to ensure the *x* positions are correct. While this sets the x-axis spacing to that of the data points, it generally does not matter for plotting purposes.